# jquery plugin imgpreload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have asked this question couple times, but non of the suggestions seems to be working.

I am using jstree plugin to build the tree. Based on the node_id, I am trying to load images to some divs. It kinda works but, I am having sporadic image display issues. Sometimes, I have to double click, sometimes single click shows the images.

I tried this:

```
  img1 = new Image;
  img1.src="teamA.png";

  img2 = new Image;
  img2.src="teamB.png";

      img1.onload = function()
 { 

$("#div1").html(img1;
    }
```

etc, but this is not working. I still see sporadicly images are now showing up on the divs.

I started looking at jquery plugin imgpreload as this:

```
$.imgpreload(['img1','img2', 'img3','img4','img5','img6'], 
{     

    each: function()     { 

    $(this).data('loaded') 

    $("#div1").html(img1);
}
});
```

this does not seem to be working either, any ideas or points?

I have done this:

```
$(function () {
var myImage1 = new Image();
$(img1)
    .load(function () {
    });


      .attr('src', 'teamA.png');
});
```

getting syntax errors. Does this seem ok to you?

*** updated *** I modified the code as this:

```
$(function () { 
    var myImage1 = new Image(); 
    $(myImage1).load(function () 
    {     
    })         
    .attr('src', 'teamA.png');
    alert(myImage1.width);  

    $('#div1').html("myImage1").css({"border": "0", "background": "white"});



}
```

Right after the load function, I am doing a:

alert(myImage.width) to see the size of the image, it is coming back at 0, so this does not seem to be working. There is definetely image.

***update v2***

```
  $(function () { 
    var myImage1 = new Image(); 
    $(myImage1).load(function () 
    {     
    alert(myImage1.width);
    $('#div1').html("myImage1").css({"border": "0", "background": "white"});

    })         
    .attr('src', 'teamA.png');
    });
```

ok, this code works assuming that the image is there.  But I like to do is if the image is not there, I like to hide that div. I have this code, but it is not working on load event. How can I hide the divs that are empty?

```
       $(function ()
           { 
            var myImage1 = new Image(); 
             $(myImage1).load(function () 
                  {  
                       var image1Check = myImage1.width;
               if (image1Check == 0  || image1Check < 30) 
                             {
                         $('#div').html("").css("border", "");

                     }
               else 
                     {

                         $("#div1").html(myImage1).css("border","1px solid");


                          }

    })         
                .attr('src', teamA.png);

    });
```

Comment: You haven't got quotes around some of your string literals, i.e. `"teamA.png"` instead of `teamA.png`, and the jQuery `each` callback refers to a non-existent variable `myImage1`.

Comment: @arxanas quotes are fixed but that is not the issue.

Comment: Bind the load events before you set the source to prevent a caching issue in IE7 and IE8

Comment: @Kevin B, how do you do that?

Comment: Move all .src lines to after the .load lines.

Comment: myImage1.onload = function() { myImage1.src="teamA.png"; $("#div1").html(myImage1).css("border","1px solid"); I am geting stack overflow error now }

Comment: The only way i could possibly be more clear would be to write the code for you. Don't set the src until after you have bound a load event to it.

Comment: @Kevin B, I appreciate your willing to help. I am very new to jquery and I really need to address this. I have place src to end and when I am trying to display that image, Im now getting img1 is undefined, something is wrong.

Comment: On your last code snippet, remove `;` after `.load()`

Comment: @Kevin B, I did remove that ; still not progress. I've update the code above. Eventhough there are images, after the load, I check the width, sometimes I get 0.

Comment: your alert needs to be inside the load event.

Comment: @Kevin B, I have one more question, I wont bother you again. It is working with a twist. I have updated the code above. If the image non existent, I would like to hide the div. Any idea, pointes?

Comment: @Kevin B, I think I got the latter question with $(myImage1).error(function(){ Thanks again for your help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the load event before setting the src, and to handle a missing image, use `.error()`

```
$(function () { 
    var myImage1 = new Image(); 
    $(myImage1).load(function () {  
        $("#div1").html(myImage1).css("border","1px solid");
    }).attr('src', "teamA.png").error(function(){
        $('#div1').html("").css("border", "");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $(this).data('loaded') in an if:

```
each: function() {
  if ($(this).data('loaded')) {
    // do something
  }
},
```

Comment: does not like this line: .attr('src', 'teamA.png');  it says syntax error

Comment: Are you on linux? is your file teamA.png or teama.png?